# Update DateUsed by trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, database-trigger

I'm trying to update a table with a trigger from another table. I thought this would be a very simple query but the query I first came up with does not work and I don't understand why.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vehicle](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [plate] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [dateUsed] [datetime] NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [vehicleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [quantity] [float] NOT NULL,
    [dateTransaction] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
```

When a transaction is added, I wish to update the Vehicle table. If the added `dateTransaction` is later then `dateUsed` it should be updated so the `dateUsed` field always contains the latest date of that specific vehicle.

I would think that this trigger should do the trick.. but it does not:

```
UPDATE [Vehicle] 
SET [dateUsed] = 
    CASE 
        WHEN [dateUsed] < [Transaction].[dateTransaction] 
            OR [dateUsed] IS NULL
            THEN [Transaction].[dateTransaction] 
        ELSE [dateUsed] 
    END
FROM [Transaction]
WHERE [Vehicle].[id]=[Transaction].[vehicleId]
```

It looks good to me... It should go over all newly inserted records and update the `dateUsed` field. If the `dateTransaction` is newer, use that one.. if not.. use the current. But I seem to missing something because it's not updating to the latest date. It does match one of the transactions of that specific vehicle but not the latest one.

A query that does work:

```
UPDATE [Vehicle] 
SET [dateUsed] = InsertedPartitioned.[dateTransaction]
FROM [Vehicle]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        [vehicleId],
        [dateTransaction],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [VehicleId] ORDER BY [dateTransaction] DESC) AS RC
    FROM [Inserted]) AS InsertedPartitioned 
    ON InsertedPartitioned.RC=1 
    AND InsertedPartitioned.[vehicleId]=[Vehicle].[id]
WHERE InsertedPartitioned.[vehicleId] IS NOT NULL
    AND ([Vehicle].[dateUsed] IS NULL 
        OR InsertedPartitioned.[dateTransaction] > [Vehicle].[dateUsed]);
```

So I have a working solution and it may even be for the better (haven't timed it with a large insert) but it bugs the hell out of my not knowing why the first it not working!

Can anyone 'enlighten me'?

Comment: Which dbms product are you using? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL... And most products' triggers are not ANSI compliant.)

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the syntax used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the first it not working

Because of a wonderful aspect of the Microsoft extension to [`UPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) that uses a `FROM` clause:

> Use caution when specifying the `FROM` clause to provide the criteria for the update operation. The results of an `UPDATE` statement are **undefined** if the statement includes a `FROM` clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated, that is if the `UPDATE` statement is not **deterministic**.

(My **emphasis**).

That is, if more than one row from `inserted` matches the same row in `Vehicle` then it's undefined *which* row will be used to apply the update - and all computations within the `SET` clause are computed "as if" they're all evaluated in parallel - so it's not as if a second attempt to update the same row will observe the results on the first attempt - the current value of the `DateUsed` column that can be observed is always the original value.

---

In ANSI standard SQL, you'd have to write the `UPDATE` without using the `FROM` extension and would thus have to write a correlated subquery, something like:

```
UPDATE [Vehicle] 
SET [dateUsed] = COALESCE((SELECT dateUsed FROM inserted i
         WHERE i.VehicleId = Vehicle.Id and
         (i.dateUsed > Vehicle.DateUsed or
          Vehicle.DateUsed IS NULL),
     dateUsed)
WHERE [id] IN (select [vehicleId] FROM inserted)
```

Which, under the same circumstances, would nicely give you an error about a subquery returning more than one value (for the one inside the `COALESCE`, not the one in the `IN`) and thus give you a clue to why it's not working.

But, undeniably, the `FROM` extension is useful - I just wish it triggered a warning for this kind of situation.

Comment: So in my update statement where i'm comparing against the current value, it's comparing against the orignal (!) value, not the value that may already have been updated since the start of the update. Am I correct?

Comment: @TieleDeclercq - yes, that's correct. It means activity *can* happen in parallel and means you can do cute things - `UPDATE tab SET colA = colB, colB = colA` swaps the values of two columns because the values on the right of the `=` are always the original values.

Comment: Okay.. it actually makes sense knowing this. Thanks!